# Intuitive explanation of Cohen's forcing (continuum hypothesis) and how Godel proved CH was consistent within ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm new to set theory and am really struggling to get my head around this. Can anyone give me an intuitive explanation so I can get a general grasp? Cheers

Comment: Is it the proof of CH in particular, or forcing in general you are trying to understand?

Comment: @J.F I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. Cohen's main achievement was showing that $\neg$CH is consistent with ZFC, by starting with a model of ZFC+CH and forcing to get a model in which $\neg$CH holds; while his method also can give you models in which CH holds from models in which CH fails, that wasn't the key part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to prove a relative independence result ("If $T$ is consistent, then $T$ doesn't prove $\varphi$") there are essentially two ways to do it:

- **Analyze the structure of $T$-proofs as combinatorial objects in their own right.** An example of this is the usual (Gödel-Rosser) proof of the second incompleteness theorem, that no recursively axiomatizable consistent theory extending PA can prove its own consistency (and in particular, Rosser's improvement on Gödel's original argument was [removing the last vestige of an appeal to models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick)).
- **Build a [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_theories,_models,_and_elementary_classes) of $T$ in which $\varphi$ fails** *(and then apply the [soundness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness))*. For example, to prove that the theory of groups doesn't prove $\forall x,y(x*y=y*x$), it suffices to exhibit an *example* of a nonabelian group, together with a proof that it is in fact a nonabelian group.

Generally, the second approach is much easier, and this is what Gödel and Cohen each did - although models of ZFC are extremely complicated objects, so rather than build appropriate models "from scratch" they showed how appropriate models could be constructed *given* "starting models" of ZFC *(which is fine - we're assuming that ZFC is consistent to begin with, and that means we can apply the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)))*. Interestingly, they went in opposite directions:

- Gödel showed that for any model $M$ of ZFC, there is a *smaller* structure $N\subseteq M$ which forms a model of ZFC+CH.
- Cohen showed that for any model $M$ of ZFC, there is a *larger* structure $M\subseteq N$ which forms a model of ZFC+$\neg$CH.

  - OK, that's not quite true: Cohen only showed that the above statement holds if $M$ is *countable*. But by the [downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), if ZFC has a model then it has a countable model, so that's fine.
  - It's also worth pointing out that Cohen's method is much  more flexible that Gödel's: Gödel's arguments cannot be used to show the consistency of ZFC+$\neg$CH, whereas Cohen's argument also lets us build models in which CH *holds*, so Cohen solves both parts of the problem while Godel solves only one. That said, Cohen's method doesn't make Gödel's obsolete, it's just superior for this particular problem.

---

That describes *what* they're doing; now, *how* did they do it?

Gödel's construction ([**inner models**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_model)) is much simpler (and so it's unsurprising that it was discovered earlier). Intuitively, we can define the [**constructible universe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) $L$ recursively by $$L_0=\emptyset,\quad L_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}_{def}(L_\alpha),\quad L_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}L_\alpha\mbox{ for $\lambda$ limit}$$ where $\mathcal{P}_{def}(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ *definable* in the structure $(X,\in)$, and let $$L=\bigcup_{\alpha\in Ord}L_\alpha.$$ It turns out that we can run this construction inside an arbitrary model of ZFC (indeed, ZF) and the result satisfies ZFC+CH (indeed, a lot more); roughly speaking, every element of $L$ is "definable" in a certain sense, so we can calculate $2^{\aleph_0}$ by counting the number of definitions of the appropriate type (although [it's actually more complicated than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_lemma)).

- The limitation of Gödel's argument mentioned above comes from the fact that $L$ is "minimal" in a precise sense - there's no hope in general that we can find a nice submodel of a given model in which CH fails, since maybe our starting model is $L$ itself.

Meanwhile, Cohen's method ([**forcing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics))) is quite involved, and too complicated to explain here. The answers to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907339/an-informal-description-of-forcing) explain it a bit, but there's just too much to say to give a good explanation. [This article by Chow](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320) may be helpful.